# Scrapy - get depth level of failed requests with no response

Tags: scrapy

When parsing scraped pages I also save the depth the request was scraped from using `response.meta['depth']`.

I recently started using `errback` to log all failed requests into a separate file and having depth there would help me a lot. (*I believe*) I could use `failure.value.response.meta['depth']` for those pages which actually got a response but failed due to ie a http status error like 403 etc., however when an error like TCPTimeout is encountered there is no response.

Is it possible to get the depth level of a failed request with no response?

EDIT1: Tried `failure.request.meta['depth']` but that gives an error. Meta seems that can be found but it has no depth key.

EDIT2: The issue seems to be that `failure.request.meta['depth']` is created only when the first response is received. So the way I understand is that if the first request, a start_url doesn't receive a response, the depth key is not yet created and hence throws an exception.

I'm going to experiment with this as per the depth middleware:

```
if 'depth' not in response.meta:
            response.meta['depth'] = 0
```

Comment: You can still access `meta` from the `failure.request` object.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the issue turns out to be exactly how I described it in EDIT2. This is how I fixed it:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for u in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(u, errback=self.my_errback)
        
def my_errback(self, failure):
    if 'depth' not in failure.request.meta:
        failure.request.meta['depth'] = 0

    depth = failure.request.meta['depth']
    # do something with depth...
```

Big thanks to mr [@Galecio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939364/gallaecio) who pointed me in the right direction!